# Dummy Browser for Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

Is there a relatively simple way to create a dummy browser, as in a browser with only the display portion, no address bar, buttons, etc. in a Codename One app? I want to build an app that is using the equivalent of a mobile site for most of the content but still uses the conventional app features for some of its functionality.

Comment: I guess I should have Googled around a little more before asking this question... didn't realize I was looking for WebView - https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `BrowserComponent` and `WebBrowser` which also works for older devices. Notice you are referencing the older javadocs see this:

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/

Also check out the component list in the developer guide (which can also be downloaded as a PDF):

http://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html